# Translation of; If X is any real number other than 1, then...

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

i've just started reading a book on number theory and am trying to follow along with the example proofs of theorems. I've not had too much trouble once I have managed to "translate" the mathematical notation into an English sentence.

Could somebody state in plain English what this says?

If $x$ is any real number other than $1$, then $$\sum_{j = 0}^{n -1} x^j = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: Try it with, say, $x=3$ and $n=4$.

Comment: To compute the sum $1+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^{n-1}$, take the (missing) term that would come next, $x^n$, subtract one, then divide by the quantity $x-1$.  For example, take $1+2+2^2+\cdots +2^6$. The next term is $2^7$, so the sum is $2^7-1\over 2-1$.

Comment: I must be doing something silly...

I get 1 + 3 + 9 + 27 = 27 / 2 !

ETA I was doing x^(n-1) rather than X^(n)-1 Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that if you add $1$ to $x$ to $x^2$ and so on, where each term is $x$ times the previous term, until you've added $n$ terms total, then you get the expression on the right.

Comment: So if n = 4 then 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 = x^(n-1) / x-1 ?

Comment: @Jacobadtr: except that you didn't set $n=4$ on the right.

Answer (score 0):

It means the formula $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ is valid for all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$, that is, all real $x \neq 1$. For $x=1$ the sum is clearly $n$.